# how to continue processing when subscriber throws an exception in rxjava?

Tags: java, rx-java

I have a `PublishSubject` and two `Subscriber` that I use to process data.
The problem is that when one of the `Subscriber` has an exception , the `Subscriber` doesn't seem to work anymore.
I'd like to ignore them and continue processing without `try-catch`. How can I do this ?

```
    Subject<Integer, Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
    Observable<Integer> observable = subject.onBackpressureBuffer().asObservable().observeOn(Schedulers.io());

    observable.subscribe(integer -> {
        if (integer == 2) {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
        System.out.println("thread-1 :" + integer);
    }, throwable -> System.out.println("thread-1 :" + throwable.getMessage()));

    observable.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("thread-2 :" + integer), throwable -> System.out.println("thread-2 :" + throwable.getMessage()));
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L);
        try {
            subject.onNext(i);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This was asked before in various forms: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rxjava+continue+after+error